# dynamically added check boxes are not displaying in listview

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to insert check boxes in list view box dynamically. The scroll bar scrolls when they are added but I can't see check boxes in list view box. it's like they are invisible.

and the other thing is when I change the code from listBox1.Items.Add(box) to listBox1.Controls.Add(box)  I see only one checkbox in list box.

This is my code as shown below :

vouchersList is a list of 15 strings.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < vouchersList.Count; i++)
 {
     CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
     box.Tag = i.ToString();
     box.Text = vouchersList[i];     
     listBox1.Items.Add(box);

 }
```

Comment: Did you get any error? Btw, just for test purpose try box.Text = i.ToString(); instead of box.Text = vouchersList[i]; and see how it works. Btw, here is a good sample; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell I am not getting any error. I have tried box.Text=i.ToString() but the same thing is happening. Scroll bar of list box scrolling as if something is adding but nothing is visible.

Comment: how ever check box in listbox appear when i change the code to listBox1.Controls.Add(box) but only one checkbox appears

Comment: Did you set the property; listView1.CheckBoxes = true; as in the example on MSDN?

Comment: @AlexBell thnx i found solution from the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use CheckedListBox insted of ListBox, and then you make something like this:

```
        CheckedListBox ClistBox1 = new CheckedListBox();
        ClistBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        ClistBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        ClistBox1.Name = "listBox1";
        ClistBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(278, 290);
        ClistBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.Controls.Add(ClistBox1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            ClistBox1.Items.Add("Box" + i, true); //Second parameter is "Checked" true or false
        }
```